# Problem in Ubuntu while running Windows 11 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-11

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I installed Windows 11 in VirtualBox in Ubuntu. When I tried starting my Windows 11 virtual instance I received the following (Please go through both screenshots.):

[image]

Comment: What happened when you did what it told you to do in the error text? Add the info to your question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added the relevant screenshots with the question itself. Kindly, go through it.

Comment: You did not answer the question in my comment. What happened when you did the `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`? Kindly, read what I write before answering.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't have the screenshot of the output, but that command got executed with any issue and I also got asked to set secure boot password, which I did.

Comment: @OrganicMarble And I ran that command again & got following output : '''sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Signing VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
'''

Comment: If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

Comment: @GothamKnight please edit your question to include additional information coherently. Avoid commenting on your own question.

Comment: So, the command didn't "get executed without any issue". **It failed**. Providing correct information to readers on this site is critical to getting your issues addressed. The simplest and easiest way to fix this is to disable Secure Boot. If you don't wish to do that, you'll need to research how to sign the drivers yourself.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah, disabling secure boot has solved the issue. Thanks for help.